# Vuetify: create image that links to another page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make an image link in my vue app. I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<v-img :src="require('@/assets/my-image.png')" to="/"></v-img>
```

I've also tried wrapping the image in a `router-link` element but no luck:

```
<router-link to="/">
    <v-img :src="require('@/assets/my-image.png')"></v-img>
</router-link>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong. This shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: As @Ruslan Isay says, you don't need the ":" before src in your case, as it seems the image name is not dynamic. The : is short hand for v-bind:src, binding it to a dynamic value. As Jon M. says, try an ordinary 'img" tag. In vuetify a v-img is actually set as a background image of a div or some such and therefore cannot be bound to a target like an actual image can.

Comment: Check if this v-img component is already present on the '/' route. Try to change it to some other route.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this (`src` vs `:src`):

```
<router-link to="/">
    <v-img src="require('@/assets/my-image.png')"></v-img>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 3):

i use some like this, and it works.

```
<a href="/">
 <v-img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')"
 max-width="60"
 to="/afiliacion"
 width="100%">  </v-img> 
</a>
```

Comment: This solution is useful in the generic situation of just wanting an image to link somewhere.