# Vuetify Nuxt.js : how to add Routing link in Carousels icon

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

js and Vuetifiy i want to add Routing link in Carousels icon. if i press icon it should open Routing link.
i tried but its not responding my link its not working
**below code i tried but note worked**

```
          {
            images: [
              { src: "/image1.png", caption: "Shopping-Page", to:"/ShoppingPage"},
              { src: "/image2.png", caption: "Cart-Page", to:"/CartPage" },
              { src: "/image3.png", caption: "main-Page", to:"/mainPage" }
              
            ]
          },
```

**My router links this below router links i want to add**

```
 to="/ShoppingPage" 

 to="/CartPage" 

 to="/mainPage"
```

**my page view locking like this**

[image]

**my code**

```
<template>
  <v-layout style="width: auto;" class="ma-auto">
    <v-carousel cycle light height="309" hide-delimiter-background show-arrows-on-hover>
      <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="3" v-for="(images, j) in slide.images" :key="j">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center">
              <v-img :src="images.src" width="30"/>
              <span class="mx-auto text-center caption">{{ images.caption }}</span>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "playground",
  data: () => ({
    slides: [
      {
        images: [
          { src: "/image1.png", caption: "Shopping-Page"},
          { src: "/image2.png", caption: "Cart-Page" },
          { src: "/image3.png", caption: "main-Page" }
          
        ]
      },
```

Comment: I cannot see any routing link in your code!

Comment: @Muhammad i mention to="/ShoppingPage" 

 to="/CartPage" 

 to="/mainPage"

Comment: alright, What you see when inspect the element in browser, is it wrapping the img in anchor tag or not.

Comment: @Muhammad i inspected the elements but it not making any anchor link

Comment: From your code your just using the src property so how should the `v-img` know if its a link or not, secondly I think `v-img` does not support any linking attribute/prop so you need to wrap the whole `v-img` in `router-link`, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779555/vuetify-create-image-that-links-to-another-page

Comment: @Muhammad can you post answer i am new in vuetify , can you guide me how to use v-img in my code

Comment: replace your `v-img` wtih the following code .
`<router-link :to="images.to">
    <v-img :src="images.src" />
</router-link>`

Comment: Great, I have moved my comment to a answer, you may accept if you you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `v-img` in a `router-link`, check the code below.

```
<router-link :to="images.to">
  <v-img :src="images.src" />
</router-link>
```